# Can't see PHP files in Emac's speedbar?

Tags: emacs

I just downloaded Emacs 23 and installed the nXhtml add-on.

I opened speedbar with `M x : speedbar`.

I can see almost all file types **except** PHP.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Finally figured out how:

```
(eval-after-load "speedbar" '(speedbar-add-supported-extension ".php"))
```

Damn, I know emacs is powerful but why these easy tasks are so difficult to solve.

Comment: You really think adding one line to config is difficult?